# Checking if a state object is empty

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react js state object and would like to execute some code if the object is empty. Is there something wrong with my logic because the code inside the if block is not getting executed.

```js
if (this.state.errors == null) {
  this.props.updateUser(user);
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

Comment: use "===" if you specifically want to check for null. Otherwise @Ankit Agarwal's answer seems comprehensive.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Given that `this.state.errors` is an object you can do this,

```
//when this.state.errors object is empty 
if (Object.keys(this.state.errors).length === 0) {
  this.props.updateUser(user);
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

`Object.keys` will return an array or all the keys from the object `this.state.errors`. Then you can check the length of that array to determine if it is an empty object or not.

Comment: I tried using the 'NOT' operator but the logic still doesn't seem to be working. I added a log statement in the block and it isn't entering the if block

Comment: Can you post what is there in `this.state`. Add a debugger and inspect its value.

Comment: I just did that and this.state.errors is an object. When there is an error, it is put into the object and when the error is fixed, it is removed from the object.

Comment: @NithinSrinivasan ok i have edited the answer. This should work now.

Comment: this unfortunately enters the block even when there are errors

Comment: You said `this.state.errors` is object that contain errors and you want the block to be executed when there are errors. So what's the problem now?

Comment: my bad for the misunderstanding. I wish for the block to be executed when there are no errors

Comment: If you want to negate the condition try `Object.keys(this.state.errors).length != 0` insted of `!Object.keys(this.state.errors).length == 0`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, You need to first check `this.state.errors` is exist or not and then for object is `null` or not

```
if (this.state.errors && !Object.keys(this.state.errors)) {
    this.props.updateUser(user);
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the state instead of the errors collection:

```
if (this.state) {
    this.props.updateUser(user);
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

*cheers*

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do like this.

```
if (this.state && !this.state.errors) {
  this.props.updateUser(user);
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

When you are accessing the values of object within another object, you might wanna check if the parent object present. If the object `this.state` is `null` or `undefined`, it just throws a console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:15
```

Answer (score -1):

-- if is Array

```
if(!this.state?.example?.length)  //ES 6 and above
```

-- if is Object

```
if(!Object.entries(this.state?.example).length)
```